# How to manipulate .9.png files in Android studio 2.1 +

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-background

I am am trying to build a simple chat app where I need to make resizable bitmaps of chat bubbles, after some googling I found in android is handled with .9.png files and I used the draw9patch tool to create all the bitmaps i needed following this tutorial [Create Resizable Bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html).

My problem is when I import the .9.png files android studio renames it to .png. Also when I store them manually in the mipmap directory android studio refuses to build my project because it does not recognize the .9.png. I can't figure out where and how to use the .9.png files within my project.

Also I found this old tutorial [Android Chat Bubbles Javapapers](http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-bubble/) that specified that .9.png files must be stored in the res/drawable but currently android studio keeps such resources in the mipmap directory, this is a bit confusing for me.

Please how do I go around this? (I managed to build the app using the files as .png but not comfortable with that).

Comment: `when I store them manually in the mipmap directory` ... the *mipmap* folder is for the **app launcher icon only**. NOT FOR ANY OTHER RESOURCE. You must use the *drawable* folders.

Comment: @Rotwang thanks, so where do I keep them and how do I do that, because when I import any image assets they are automatically stored in the mipmap folder

Comment: Simply make all your needed **drawable** folder/s (at least, one per each supported density).